# ASP.NET Checkbox control in the Repeater is always unchecked

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, user-controls, repeater

I have problem with my own created User control. If I click on the checkbox the `Checked` property is always `false`, why ?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true" CodeBehind="MyCtrl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyCtrl" %>

<asp:CheckBox ID="attrCb" runat="server"
              AutoPostBack="true" 
              oncheckedchanged="cb_CheckedChanged" />
```

cs file

```
public bool IsChecked { get { return ViewState["IsChecked"] != null ? (bool)ViewState["IsChecked"] : false; } set { ViewState["IsChecked"] = value; } }

protected void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsChecked = attrCb.Checked;
}
```

aspx snippet

```
<asp:Repeater ID="QuestionnaireRepeater" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>                            
                        <td><mytag:MyCtrl OnCheckedChange="On_CheckedChanged" ID="attrCb1" runat="server" /></td>
                        <td><mytag:MyCtrl OnCheckedChange="On_CheckedChanged" ID="attrCb2" runat="server" /></td>
                        <td><mytag:MyCtrl OnCheckedChange="On_CheckedChanged" ID="attrCb3" runat="server" /></td>
                        <td><mytag:MyCtrl OnCheckedChange="On_CheckedChanged" ID="attrCb4" runat="server" /></td>
                        <td><mytag:MyCtrl OnCheckedChange="On_CheckedChanged" ID="attrCb5" runat="server" /></td>
                        <td><mytag:MyCtrl OnCheckedChange="On_CheckedChanged" ID="attrCb6" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

### edit

I've made some changes, it doesn't work too (according to the [Exposing Events from asp.net usercontrols to container web forms page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346324/exposing-events-from-asp-net-usercontrols-to-container-web-forms-page))

I still see `false`

inside MyCtrl.ascx

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="attrCb" runat="server"
              AutoPostBack="true"
              oncheckedchanged="Cb_CheckedChanged1" />
```

inside MyCtrl.cs I added

```
    public event EventHandler CheckedChange;
    private void OnCheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        var e = CheckedChange;

        if (e != null)
            e(this, ea);
    }

    protected void Cb_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnCheckedChange(sender, e);
    }
```

inside my aspx page:

```
    protected void On_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCrtl cbCtrl = ((MyCrtl)sender);

        cbCtrl.IsChecked = cbCtrl.attrCb.Checked; //attrCb is exposed
                                                 //Checked is still false
    }
```

Comment: You need to expose the CheckChanged event inside your control and then wire up that event for each MyCtrl user control within the ASPX page. The control flow as you described won't work.

Comment: I've made some changes, please see my edited post